# Positioning Images for all browsers using html5 and css

Tags: html, css

so just finished making my website using HTML5 and CSS3 coding and when i view the website on chrome (browser i used to test my website throughout the creation process), the emblem image comes out exactly where i want it to. However, when i view my website in internet explorer, that one image is displaced (not where i want it to be). Ive tried messing around with the absolute, fixed and relative positions, but nothing seem to work. Everything, but that one image is in place on both browser. I want to make it work on all browser to the best i can. Cans someone please help me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Websites</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #top, #bottom, #left, #right {
                background: #000015;
                position: fixed;
            }
            #left, #right {
                top: 0; bottom: 0;
                width: 50px;
            }
            #left { left: 0; }
            #right { right: 0; }

            #top, #bottom {
                left: 0; right: 0;
                height: 50px;
            }
            #top { top: 0; }
            #bottom { bottom: 0; }

            th, td {
                padding: 15px;
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 180px;
                z-index:100;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            td {
                text-align: center;
                font-family:"Times New Roman", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                font-size: 15pt;
                border-radius:5px
            }

            .center{
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .bottomright{
                position: fixed;
                bottom:-2%;
                right:0.5%  
            }

            a {
                color:#00003D;
                text-decoration:none
            }

            a:hover {
                color: orange;
                font-size: 105%;
            }

            .circle {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
                opacity: .9;
                border-right: 5px solid;
                border-left: 5px solid ;
                border-radius: 50px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                animation: spinPulse 1s infinite linear;
                -webkit-animation: spinPulse 1s infinite linear;
            }

            .circle1 {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
                opacity: .9;
                border-left: 5px solid;
                border-right: 5px solid;
                border-radius: 50px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                position: relative;
                top: -30px;
                animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
                -webkit-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
            }

            @keyframes spinPulse {
                0% {
                    transform: rotate(160deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
                }
                50% {
                    transform: rotate(145deg);
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                100% {
                    transform: rotate(-320deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                }   
            }

            @keyframes spinoffPulse {
                0% {
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }
                100% {
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes spinPulse {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(160deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
                }
                50% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg);
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg);
                    opacity: 0;
                }   
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes spinoffPulse {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                }

                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }       

            img.growturn {
                transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
            }

            img.growturn:hover {
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background:url(webdata/images/index/background.png) no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-size:100% 100%;">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>

        <div class="center">
            <table class="button">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        /*this image (emblem.png) is the one causing problems*/
                        <img class="growturn" src="webdata/images/index/emblem.png" alt="" height="45" width="45" style="position: fixed; left:28%; top:6%">
                        <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 15pt; color: white;">PROJECT <strong>COSC</strong>2206</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="font-family:Geneva, 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif; font-size: 40pt; color: orange">WELCOME TO MY WEBSITE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 9pt; color:#C2F0FF; letter-spacing: 1px; padding: 20px">Welcome to Project COSC2206. All assignments can be viewed below once they become available or simply return to the iTool's.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="#">tools</a></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="classified.html">Assignment 2</a></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="classified.html">Assignment 3</a></td>
                    <td style="background-color:#00CCFF;"><a href="classified.html">Assignment 4</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
        </div>  



        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcoscvm23.cs.laurentian.ca%2F;outline=1" target="_blank">
            <img src="webdata/images/index/HTML5_Badge.png" alt="" width="28" height="27" style="position: absolute; float: left; left: 7px; bottom: 5px;">
        </a>    
        <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" target="_blank">
            <img src="webdata/images/index/CSS3.png" alt="" width="31" height="31" style="position: absolute; float: left; left: 35px; bottom: 2px;">
        </a>

        <div class="bottomright">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle1"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem. I checked in three browsers, chrome, firefox and internet explorer. However this problem can be due to Browser's css. You should use `!important` at the end of CSS position property and second thing is to try to reduce the percentage of `top` `left`  slighlty so that it is not misplaced due to little margin.

Comment: also, i tried my website on 2 different computers, opening my site on both IE and Chrome, im getting the same results where in IE the image is way to far above the desired position.